# Recognize datetime in 20211124_1502 format with Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, date-time

I have a column in an Excel table with datetimes in this format:

```
20211124_1502
```

I tried different formatting options for these cells (Date, Short date, etc.) but the date is never recognized/parsed (then I cannot filter by months with `Autofilter`, etc.)

**Is there a simple way for Excel to automatically recognize these datetimes?** (*without* having to use a second column with a formula to manipulate and parse the strings from this column).

Comment: Try setting the column format to `YYYYmmdd_HHmm`.

Comment: I already tried, it's `aaaammjj_hhMM` in my French version (why on earth did MS rename these things in localized versions of Excel?), but with no result. Can you maybe show in a screenshot what you did exactly, and how you can see it is well parsed @ReddyLutonadio?

Comment: Can the downvoter leave a comment explaining how to make the question better? (screenshot? more details?) Thanks!

Comment: I haven't tested, but I think the date format option only works on numeric data. Your data is text because of the `_`. so you need your extra column/formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is NO way excel will recognize that text string as a date. It needs to be manipulated in a second column (or in place using VBA) to something Excel can recognize as a date. Then you will be able to format it.

One method: Use a formula to convert that text string to an actual Excel Date.

```
=--(TEXT(--SUBSTITUTE(A1,"_",""),"0000\/00\/00 00\:00"))
```

Then you can format it as a date however you want,